# android fails to convert string to jsonarray

Tags: android, arrays, json, rest, go

Hey I programmed a golang rest service and it works fine!
The problem is that I need the service in my android app, so I need a JSONArray or a JSONObject.

When I call the service like this I have no problems

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d("RESPONSE: ",response);
}
```

But when I try to call the service like this

```
JsonArrayRequest req= new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
}
```

It fails to convert the json.

I dont really know wheres my fault is..
Thank you 
John

Comment: And did you checked the json format ? Since it failed to convert it... PS : This should throw an exception, it should be present on this post. And I don't think the `golang` part is necessary. Basicly you are trying to convert a Json on an Android app.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set Header with Api call check this code it will help to fix your issue

```
 public void makeJsonArrayRequest(Context context, String url, final String requestTag, final ServiceCallBack listener) {

    final ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.show();


    JsonArrayRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonArrayRequest(
            url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                    listener.onSuccess(requestTag, response.toString());

                    pDialog.hide();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            // hide the progress dialog
            listener.onFailure(requestTag, error.getMessage());

            pDialog.hide();
        }


    }) {

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            return headers;
        }
    };

    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq, requestTag);

}
```

[VolleyExample](https://github.com/rkoshti/VolleyWithGSON/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/rajesh/volleysample/utils/VolleyRequestHandler.java)

Comment: Please, see [answer] about link. You should extract what is important to preserve this answer in time (the link could be broken in the futur)